# Partial sum based on the values of another field

Tags: python, django, django-views

Given a model like this (example for the purpose of generalization):

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 64 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |

How could I make a sum for each group and obtain the results for the sum of each group instead of the total sum of all the groups?

Until now I had done sums like this:

```
total_value = myModel.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('value'))

The result would be: 2 + 5 + 64 + 1 + 4 = 76
```

Expected result (list or dict if possible):

```
Group 1: 71
Group 2: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyModel.objects.values('group').annotate(sum=Sum('value'))
```